# SceneKit UIImage material is black

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, scenekit, arkit

I'm loading images from the photo library via UIImagePickerController and with that image I'm setting the material of a SCNPlane:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = imageView
```

With some images, this works fine, no problem at all, the image shows up properly. However, with other images, the texture of the plane shows up as entirely black and Xcode prints "Unsupported IOSurface format: 0x00000000". It seems to be only images that were screenshots causing this, although some screenshot images work just fine.

Comment: Since contents can take various types of input (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents) did you try to use UIColor with the image pattern? Or create a texture object based on the image? Or provide the image path?

Comment: Are you using .jpg or .png? iOS wants you to use .png rather than .jpg.

Comment: I looked at the extensions of some of the images and the ones that don't work are actually PNGs while the JPEGs work.

Comment: @YamingLin so, jpegs seem to work fine, but also some pngs work while others do not. Do you have any idea why this would be the case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SceneKit can display both PNGs and JPGs, some PNGs just seem to cause issues. Not sure why or whether it's a bug or not. What you can do that's probably better than converting everything to JPGs (so you can retain transparency) is set your material contents to the image's CGImage:

```
if let cgImage = image.cgImage {
    geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = cgImage
}
```

You can also convert your image to a JPEG via something like this, as SceneKit doesn't seem to have issues with JPGs:

```
if let jpegData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
    image = UIImage(data: jpegData)!
}
```

You will lose transparency doing it this way however.